# Do Bluetooth codecs change data rate to counter signal loss / interference?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

> Out of curiosity. Not sure whether this is the right place within the Stack universe to ask this.

I know that different bluetooth audio codecs provide different sound quality, and that the quality also depends on a codec's configuration. [Overview for example from Wirecutter.](https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/blog/what-you-need-to-know-about-bluetooth-audio/) What I'd like to know is whether audio devices adjust the codec settings on the fly to compensate for bad connections.

For example, if I play a sound file on my Android device on my car stereo, and something interferes with the bluetooth signal, causing package loss or delay, would the mobile reduce the bitrate in order to ensure that the audio goes on without stopping/stuttering?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth will address these types of issues at the radio layer. Therefore it uses [Adaptive Frequency Hopping](https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/how-bluetooth-technology-uses-adaptive-frequency-hopping-to-overcome-packet-interference/) which then avoids the disturbed frequencies.

The audio codec negotiation takes place at the beginning of a connection and is not repeated during the connection.